# How can I use Jenkins to deploy a project that depends on another project on GIT?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, jenkins-workflow

I am absolutly new in **Jenkins** and I have the following problem.

I have 2 jobs representing 2 different projects which are related to each other.

In particular I have the following situation:

I have a main project named **main-project**: this is a Java EE project. Then I have a Flex project named **client-project** that represent the web client of the previous project.

Both these project are stored in a specific **GIT** repository (so I have a specific GIT repository for the **main-project** Java EE project and another specific repository for the **client-project**).

The 2 projects (on my local machine) are related in the following way:

The **main-project** contains the **.swf** file that represent the compiled version of the **client-project**.

Something like this:

```
\main-project\src\main\webapp\Main.swf
```

So as you can see into the **\src\main\webapp** directory of my **main-project** is manually putted the **Main.swf** file that represent the compilation of the Flex **client-project**.

Ok, so my problem is: I have 2 **Jenkins** jobs related to these project.

1) **main-project-job:** that is the Jenkins job that compile and deploy on the srver the **main-project** project.

2) **client-project-job:** this job I think should do nothing (it only retrieve the latest compiled version of the **client-project** project.

I have to automate the building process in this way:

After that a dveloper push on **GIT** a new version of the **main-project** project the **main-project-job** compile and deploy it on server. When this job ends start the **client-project-job** that replace the **Main.swf** file into the **\DEPLOYED-PROJECT\src\main\webapp** path on my deployed project on the server.

How can I do something like this using Jenkins? Is it a neat solution to keep synchronized the latest version of the **main-project** and of the **client-project**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a few leads that you might want to explore.

### 1. Deploy main-project-job with the embedded swf

As your main-project seems to depend heavily on your swf file (it should probably not be deployed without the swf file), can't you just get and put the swf file as part of the compiled main-project artifact ? It would seem logical to mee that your deployed main-project already contains the swf file at the time it is deployed.

With Jenkins pipelines, something like this would be pretty easy to do :

```
stage("Build main project") {
    // your build step
}

stage("Copy client project to main webapp") {
    git 'your-git/client-project'
    sh "cp client-project/generated-swf /main-project/src/main/webapp/Main.swf"
}

stage("Deploy main project") {
    // your deploy step
}
```

### 2. Copy swf file as part of the main job

If you cannot integrate the swf file directly to the main-project before deploy, you could still use the same job to do that, again if the main project heavily depends on the swf file, you probably want to copy it as part of the job. In this case, only the copy step will change and you will need to use some `scp` command to copy the swf file to the deployed app, on the distant server.

Something along these lines :

```
stage("Build main project") {
    // your build step
}

stage("Copy client project to main webapp") {
    git 'your-git/client-project'
    sh "scp client-project/generated-swf user@deployServer:/main-project/src/main/webapp/Main.swf"
}

stage("Deploy main project") {
    // your deploy step
}
```

### 3. Copy swf file as part of a separate job

If you are sure that you want to make the copy action as part of another job (let's say, if you sometimes needs to manually trigger the job to copy the modified swf file in the running webapp, on the server), you can just trigger another job from the main-project-job :

**main-project-job**

```
stage("Build main project") {
    // your build step
}

stage("Deploy main project") {
    // your deploy step
}

stage("Copy client project to main webapp") {
    build job: copy-client-project
}
```

**copy-client-project**

```
stage("Copy client project to main webapp") {
    git 'your-git/client-project'
    sh "scp client-project/generated-swf user@deployServer:/main-project/src/main/webapp/Main.swf"
}
```

One last detail: if you do decide to use a separate job for copy, I would recommend not calling the job "client-project-job" which often implies a standard build/deploy job, instead I would name it "copy-client-files" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

*> How can I do something like this using Jenkins?*

Sounds to me like that's can be easily done with the [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) or something similar.
Just add a post-build step `Trigger/call builds on other projects` to **main-project-job** which will start **client-project-job**.

If that's not enough for some reason, please add further details on needed workflow.

Comment: Ok, but the client-project-build doesn't perform a concrete build. It only have to retrieve from GIT the latest version of the Main.swf file and put it into the "\main-project\src\main\webapp\" folder of the main poject deployed at the prevous step. Can I do it?

Comment: @blablablablablabla, yes you can. As long as both builds are performed at one slave, that's as easy as launching `cp` command in "Execute shell" step (or `COPY` in "Execute Windows batch command"). If these builds exist at different slaves, you'll have to use something like [Copy to Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin).

Comment: Though I had to mention you likely don't want to store an artifact in a git repository. It's designed to store sources. For artifacts, there are other services like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) to name some.